# No implementation for play.cache.CacheApi annotated with @play.cache.NamedCache(value=session-cache) was bound on Production

Tags: java, caching, playframework, config, playframework-2.4

I'm using `@NamedCache` annotation without any problem in dev mode by using activator run. I've specified caches other than default cache called **play** in *application.conf* file as `play.cache.bindCaches = ["user-cache", "session-cache"]`. This works fine without any problem as I've checked getting named cache by using CacheManager.

However, in production mode. I'm using `activator dist` command. Then, unzip created created snapshot found in *target\universal\project-name* address.After that I'm using 
`java -Dhttp.port=9000 -Dconfig.resource=application.conf -cp "../lib/*;../conf" play.core.server.ProdServerStart` command to start application in production mode.

When I use `@NamedCache` annotation in production it gives error:

```
1) No implementation for play.cache.CacheApi annotated with @play.cache.NamedCache(value=session-cache) was bound.
while locating play.cache.CacheApi annotated with @play.cache.NamedCache(value=session-cache)
for field at services.space.SessionSpace.cache(SessionSpace.java:19)
while locating services.space.SessionSpace
for field at services.SecurityService.sessionSpace(SecurityService.java:21)
while locating services.SecurityService
for field at common.Response.securityService(Response.java:17)
while locating common.Response
for field at controllers.BaseController.response(BaseController.java:53)
while locating controllers.Application
for parameter 2 at router.Routes.<init>(Routes.scala:60)
while locating router.Routes
while locating play.api.inject.RoutesProvider
while locating play.api.routing.Router
```

After getting this error, I've removed NamedCache's and used default cache. When I do that, everything works fine. Again, in dev mode NamedCache works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I was encountering similar problem. But in my case I was injecting the cache api which i use in one of my project dependencies (which was also developed by me). I learnt that the mistake was any application.conf inside you project dependencies will be overwritten. i.e conf/appliaction.conf will override all the other application.conf's if you are using a dependency which was developmed in play. Solution:
All your application.confs must be named as reference.conf inside your dependencies.
Are you using the cache in one of your dependencies?

Cheers,
Mani.